# loading gif before while image loads, then image fades in

Tags: jquery

Here's the jsfiddle I've been messing around with: http://jsfiddle.net/Hrs2a/

Basically, I'm trying to get the loading image to come up while the image is loading and then have the image fade in when it's fully loaded.

I tried to follow the tutorial [here](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-loading/) but couldn't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is this supposed to work, when the `img` never gets into the DOM?

**EDIT:**

Look at this fiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/9VmWA/ I think it does what you want.

Comment: I don't know =/. I'm a beginner with this so please excuse any obvious errors.

Comment: Yeah, that works but is there a way to still keep the image hover effect I had in the original fiddle? Where if you hover over the image, you can see the text/links?

Comment: That is kind of outside the scope of this question...but yes.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that in the original post. If you can help me out with that I'd appreciate it. Either way, thanks for the help.

Comment: OK, I'll modify my Fiddle to include a description like yours.